# ScrollTo keeps scrolling too far down

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollto

I have a ul list that I am trying to make scroll down by the height of the li's inside it (to create a vertical slider) using the latest version of JQuery ScrollTo (v. 1.4.11).
It is scrolling up an down and working almost as expected.
But always seems to scroll 6px to far down which pushes it out of position when scrolling back up again.

The site is responsive and the li's will drop to the next line when needed, (max of 4 li's showing at one time, it will drop down to 3 etc, and still scroll properly).
I have tried using offset in the function but that made no difference.
If set a -6px margin bottom on the li's it seems to fix it in desktop browsers to certain extent (Firefox and opera still scroll 1px to far) but on all mobiles and tablets the top of the li's behind start showing below.
The rest of the site is using HTML5 and CSS3.

I think it has something to do with an invisible horizontal scrollbar, is that true? 
And if so how can I fix it?

My code is below:

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li>list one</li>
  <li>list two</li>
  <li>list three</li>
  <li>list four</li>
  <li>list six</li>
  <li>list seven</li>
  <li>list eight</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul { 
    height: 225px !important; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    max-width: 960px; 
    width: 95%; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
}

li { 
    display: inline-block; 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    width: 190px; 
    height: 225px !important; 
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Javascript

```
var getHeight = $("ul li").height();
var scroll = function (scroll) {
    if (scroll == 'down') {
        scroll = '-=' + getHeight + 'px';
    }
    else if (scroll == 'up') {
        scroll = '+=' + getHeight + 'px';
    };
    $('ul').scrollTo(scroll, 300, { offset: -6 });
};
$('.widget-HomePagePortfolio span.prev').bind('click', function() {
    scroll('down');
});
$('.widget-HomePagePortfolio span.next').bind('click', function () {
    scroll('up');
});
```

Any help would greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BWPBL/ what changes do you want to this and to make scroll appear overlow:hidden have to be changed to overflow:auto/scroll

Comment: I don't want the scroll to appear, I wanted to use scrollTo function to on click events of a prev and next button. As mentioned I have it working, and scrolling up and down fine, but for some reason it keeps trying to scroll 6px further

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BWPBL/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is late, but if anyone does come across this or a similar problem, I found out that the problem was down to the `<li>` elements being `display: inline-block`. This meant the item always had superfluous spacing. By using `float: left` instead this solved the issue.